# Additional inputs for Shiny module only get updated once

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, shinymodules

I tried boiling this down to a minimal example, but I think I have to provide more or less the full code to show the problem.

Basically I want a shiny app to act as a user friendly GUI to start/stop (multiple) system processes (mostly BASH scripts, for scientific workflows) through the processx package. So I made a shiny module that can start/stop and show a process log (just output from stderr+stdout). The script/command run is decided when calling the module, not in the module itself. It's then important that additional options can be passed on to the different processes depending on the script run, like choosing input/output folders, database files, settings, etc.

**The issue** is that the value of any additional inputs does not get updated every time the actionButton is clicked, so clicking the start button again (triggering the eventReactive) just starts the process again without the new options/setting.

I have attached the full code here and published an example app on my shinyapps.io account, available here: https://kasperskytte.shinyapps.io/processxmodule/

```
library(shiny)

#shiny module to start asynchronous processes using processx package

#shiny must be version 1.4.0.9003 or later to use shiny modules, install from github
installGitHub <- function(...) {
  if(!require("remotes")) {
    install.packages("remotes")
  }
  remotes::install_github(...)
}

if(any(grepl("^shiny$", installed.packages()[,1]))) {
  if(packageVersion("shiny") < "1.4.0.9003") {
    installGitHub("rstudio/shiny")
  }
} else 
  installGitHub("rstudio/shiny")

require("shiny")
require("processx")

processxUI <- function(id) {
  shiny::tagList(
    uiOutput(NS(id, "startStopBtn")),
    p(),
    uiOutput(NS(id, "processStatus")),
    h4("Process log"),
    verbatimTextOutput(NS(id, "processLog")),
    downloadButton(NS(id, "downloadLogfile"), label = "Export log file")
  )
}

processxServer <- function(id, ...) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    #reactive to store processx R6 class object
    process <- reactiveVal()
    
    #reactive to store logfile created on start
    logfile <- reactiveVal(tempfile())
    
    #start/stop button
    output$startStopBtn <- renderUI({
      if(isFALSE(processAlive())) {
        actionButton(
          inputId = NS(id, "startStopProcess"),
          label = "Start process"
        )
      } else if(isTRUE(processAlive())) {
        actionButton(
          inputId = NS(id, "startStopProcess"),
          label = "Kill process"
        )
      }
    })
    
    #start a new process and logfile when actionbutton is pressed
    observeEvent(input$startStopProcess, {
      #start process if not already running, otherwise kill
      startProcess <- function(...) {
        #generate new log file for each new process
        logfile(tempfile())
        #start process piping stderr+stdout to logfile
        process(
          processx::process$new(
            ...,
            stderr = "2>&1",
            stdout = logfile(),
            supervise = TRUE
          )
        )
      }
      if(is.null(process()$is_alive))
        startProcess(...)
      else if(!is.null(process()$is_alive))
        if(isTRUE(process()$is_alive()))
          process()$kill_tree()
      else if(isFALSE(process()$is_alive()))
        startProcess(...)
    })
    
    #read process status every 500 ms (alive or not)
    #(only for updating status message below, otherwise use 
    # process()$is_alive() to avoid refresh interval delay)
    processAlive <- reactivePoll(
      intervalMillis = 500,
      session = session,
      checkFunc = function() {
        if(!is.null(process()$is_alive))
          process()$is_alive()
        else
          FALSE
      },
      valueFunc = function() {
        if(!is.null(process()$is_alive))
          process()$is_alive()
        else
          FALSE
      }
    )
    
    #print status message of process and exit status if finished
    output$processStatus <- renderUI({
      if(isTRUE(processAlive())) {
        p("Process is running...")
      } else if(isFALSE(processAlive()) && !is.null(process()$get_exit_status)) {
        if(process()$get_exit_status() == 0)
          p("Process has finished succesfully")
        else if(process()$get_exit_status() == -9)
          p("Process was killed")
        else if(!process()$get_exit_status() %in% c(0, -9))
          p(paste0("Process has errored (exit status: ", process()$get_exit_status(), ")"))
      }
    })
    
    #read logfile every 500 ms
    readLogfile <- reactivePoll(
      intervalMillis = 500,
      session = session,
      checkFunc = function() {
        if(file.exists(logfile()))
          file.info(logfile())[["mtime"]][1]
        else
          return('No process has run yet')
      },
      valueFunc = function() {
        if(file.exists(logfile()))
          readLines(logfile())
        else
          return('No process has run yet')
      }
    )
    
    #print process logfile
    output$processLog <- renderText({
      readLogfile()
    },
    sep = "\n")
    
    #export process logfile
    output$downloadLogfile <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        #append module id and date to logfile filename
        paste0("logfile_", id, "_", format(Sys.time(), format = "%y%m%d_%H%M%S"), ".txt")
      },
      content = function(file) {
        file.copy(from = logfile(), to = file)
      },
      contentType = "text/plain"
    )
  })
}

ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "test",
  tabPanel(
    title = "Test",
    column(
      width = 4,
      wellPanel(
        sliderInput(
          NS("process1", "delay"),
          "Sleep delay",
          min = 1,
          max = 5, 
          step = 1,
          value = 2)
      )
    ),
    column(
      width = 8,
      fluidRow(
        processxUI("process1")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  processxServer(
    "process1",
    command = "echo",
    args = as.character(reactive({input[[NS("process1", "delay")]]})())
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that you don't pass a reactive to your module. In the line

```
processxServer(
    "process1",
    command = "echo",
    args = as.character(reactive({input[[NS("process1", "delay")]]})())
  )
```

you evaluate your `reactive` before passing it to the module, therefore the module only gets the default at startup. I've changed it so that the unevaluated `reactive` is passed to the module and only evaluated when you make the `startProcess` function. However, this makes you a bit less flexible with the `...` because now `startProcess` assumes that there is the argument `args` passed.

```
library(shiny)
library("processx")

#shiny module to start asynchronous processes using processx package

processxUI <- function(id) {
  shiny::tagList(
    uiOutput(NS(id, "startStopBtn")),
    p(),
    uiOutput(NS(id, "processStatus")),
    h4("Process log"),
    verbatimTextOutput(NS(id, "processLog")),
    downloadButton(NS(id, "downloadLogfile"), label = "Export log file")
  )
}

processxServer <- function(id, ...) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    #reactive to store processx R6 class object
    process <- reactiveVal()
    
    #reactive to store logfile created on start
    logfile <- reactiveVal(tempfile())
    
    #start/stop button
    output$startStopBtn <- renderUI({
      if(isFALSE(processAlive())) {
        actionButton(
          inputId = NS(id, "startStopProcess"),
          label = "Start process"
        )
      } else if(isTRUE(processAlive())) {
        actionButton(
          inputId = NS(id, "startStopProcess"),
          label = "Kill process"
        )
      }
    })
    
    #start a new process and logfile when actionbutton is pressed
    observeEvent(input$startStopProcess, {
      #start process if not already running, otherwise kill
      startProcess <- function(...) {
        #generate new log file for each new process
        logfile(tempfile())
        #start process piping stderr+stdout to logfile
        
        # make argument list
        dots <- list(...)
        dots$args <- as.character(dots$args())
        arg_list <- c(dots, stderr = "2>&1", stdout = logfile(), supervise = TRUE)
        
        process(
          do.call(processx::process$new, arg_list)
        )
      }
      if(is.null(process()$is_alive))
        startProcess(...)
      else if(!is.null(process()$is_alive))
        if(isTRUE(process()$is_alive()))
          process()$kill_tree()
      else if(isFALSE(process()$is_alive()))
        startProcess(...)
    })
    
    #read process status every 500 ms (alive or not)
    #(only for updating status message below, otherwise use 
    # process()$is_alive() to avoid refresh interval delay)
    processAlive <- reactivePoll(
      intervalMillis = 500,
      session = session,
      checkFunc = function() {
        if(!is.null(process()$is_alive))
          process()$is_alive()
        else
          FALSE
      },
      valueFunc = function() {
        if(!is.null(process()$is_alive))
          process()$is_alive()
        else
          FALSE
      }
    )
    
    #print status message of process and exit status if finished
    output$processStatus <- renderUI({
      if(isTRUE(processAlive())) {
        p("Process is running...")
      } else if(isFALSE(processAlive()) && !is.null(process()$get_exit_status)) {
        if(process()$get_exit_status() == 0)
          p("Process has finished succesfully")
        else if(process()$get_exit_status() == -9)
          p("Process was killed")
        else if(!process()$get_exit_status() %in% c(0, -9))
          p(paste0("Process has errored (exit status: ", process()$get_exit_status(), ")"))
      }
    })
    
    #read logfile every 500 ms
    readLogfile <- reactivePoll(
      intervalMillis = 500,
      session = session,
      checkFunc = function() {
        if(file.exists(logfile()))
          file.info(logfile())[["mtime"]][1]
        else
          return('No process has run yet')
      },
      valueFunc = function() {
        if(file.exists(logfile()))
          readLines(logfile())
        else
          return('No process has run yet')
      }
    )
    
    #print process logfile
    output$processLog <- renderText({
      readLogfile()
    },
    sep = "\n")
    
    #export process logfile
    output$downloadLogfile <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        #append module id and date to logfile filename
        paste0("logfile_", id, "_", format(Sys.time(), format = "%y%m%d_%H%M%S"), ".txt")
      },
      content = function(file) {
        file.copy(from = logfile(), to = file)
      },
      contentType = "text/plain"
    )
  })
}

ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "test",
  tabPanel(
    title = "Test",
    column(
      width = 4,
      wellPanel(
        sliderInput(
          NS("process1", "delay"),
          "Sleep delay",
          min = 1,
          max = 5, 
          step = 1,
          value = 2)
      )
    ),
    column(
      width = 8,
      fluidRow(
        processxUI("process1")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  processxServer(
    "process1",
    command = "echo",
    args = reactive({input[[NS("process1", "delay")]]})
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Also, your definition of the `delay` slider is a bit outside of the shiny module concept. `NS` is thought to be called in the module `ui`, so that the definition of which elements belong to which namespace is clearly separated (but it obviously also works with your approach).

Comment: Thank you very much! I see now, that solved the issue. I know it's not exactly by the book doing it this way when using shiny modules, but I don't see any other options. I currently have 8 different processes to run from within the same app, so having to have 8x replicate code just because a few inputs are different really bothers me.